# Flask putting form into URL

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I've been working on a form that sends data to a scraper and simultaneously generates a URL from form input. The returned templates works flawlessly, but the URL change ends up giving me the entire form in the URL and I can't figure out why.

The URL ends up looking like this:

```
http://localhost/options/%3Cinput%20id%3D%22symbol%22%20name%3D%22symbol%22%20type%3D%22text%22%20value%3D%22%22%3E
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
http://localhost/options/ABC
```

Form class:

```
class OptionsForm(Form):
    symbol = StringField('Enter a ticker symbol:', validators=[Required(), Length(min=1, max=5)])
    submit = SubmitField('Get Options Quotes')
```

Views:

```
# Where the form data ends up
@app.route('/options/<symbol>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def options(symbol):
# Created this try/except so I could test functionality - for example, I can do 'localhost/options/ABC' and it works
    try:
        symbol = request.form['symbol']
    except:
        pass
    return render_template('options.html', symbol=symbol, company_data=OS.pull_data(symbol, name=True))

# Where the form lives
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = OptionsForm()
    print(form.errors)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('options', symbol=form.symbol.data))
    return render_template('index.html', options_form=form)
```

Template:

```
<div id="options_div">
<form method="POST" name="symbol_form" action="{{ url_for('options', symbol=options_form.symbol) }}">
    {{ options_form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ options_form.symbol(size=10) }}
    {{ options_form.submit(size=10) }}
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to the form tag. It looks like your form is using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the default.

**Edit** OK so check this out. When your template is being rendered there is no value in that data attribute (In the url_for call). When not referencing the data attribute (as your original question shows), you're referencing the actual form element (which is why you see all of that html being passed in the url). Here are your options (that I see):

1. Use some kind of frontend javascript to bind the form's action attribute to the value in the input box. Something like angular would help for this (but is overkill if you don't use any of its other features).
2. Just have the form POST to /options (no symbol in url). Then, grab the symbol attribute from the form data.

Comment: Just gave that a shot and it still gives me the garbled URL. Thanks for the idea, though.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it has to do with symbol=options_form.symbol in url_for call. I've not used WTForms before but maybe it needs to be something like symbol=options_form.symbol.text or .value or something

Comment: Tried that as well (in WTForms it's .data). When I did it, the page with the form itself (the index view) wouldn't load - it gave me a werkzeug.routing.BuildError message. Any other ideas? Either way, thank you again for taking the time to consider this.

Comment: I'm going to remove the URL changing feature for now and revisit it later with JavaScript per your suggestion. Thanks!